# ADF mobile - invoking webservice in iphone simulator fails

Tags: macos, mobile, simulator, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am deploying an adf mobile application on an iOS simulator per the below
- have a web service running on a standalone WLS .
- The ADF mobile application is created in jdeveloper in a Mac with a embedded WLS
- This mobile app is created using the web service wsdl URL. (This wsdl url itself runs fine in the iphone simulator)
- when deploying to  iOS simulator it says
HTTP status code 500
Internal Server Error: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Also
- created a adf web application using the same wsdl url on the same jdeveloper - runs fine.
- created another mobile adf application using a EO/VO - runs fine in the ios simulator.

Comment: Can one of the gurus answer this please?

Comment: I just checked no errors in webservice and - input and output are both just strings.
 
 
To test I just created a plsql package/function based on input varchar2 and output varchar2.
It simply returns the incoming parameter. Published this package as  a web service using the database navigator.
And I am creating a mobile form using that. And in the iphone emulator I come across this issue. (the same web service works fine in adf web application).
 
Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Does the WSDL open in the emulator browser?? Check that out first. Even I had a similar problem that it did not open in the emulator browser. So the problem was with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that inside the WSDL it's not pointing to localhost or 127.0.0.1